# PHP Upload Won't Work

Tags: php, upload

I made a php upload script that would be executed after a form with the upload was submitted.

```
$game_tmp = $game_file['tmp_name'];
$game_name = $game_file['name'];
$game_dest = "/games/" . game_name;

if (move_uploaded_file($game_tmp, $game_dest)) {
    echo "<b>SUCCESS:</b><br />";
}
else {
    echo "Error.";
}
```

It always output Error, so I checked my php.ini file and phpinfo(). my php.ini shows     upload_tmp_dir with no value and so does the value in phpinfo(). I changed the calue of the directory to /upload, and changed the open_basedir to have a value of upload_tmp_dir. Yet, when I look into phpinfo(), it still shows upload_tmp_dir with a local and master value of *no value*. I believe this is the problem that is stopping my upload script from working. I created a /upload folder also and gave its permission value 777. Yet, this problem persists. I am not sure what is causing this problem.

Comment: and tmp_name for the file gives me /tmp/php4A6B2o. It gives me /tmp/php and a random combination of numbers and letters afterwards. /tmp/php4A6B2o, in this case.

Comment: Try investigate if file uploaded with errors. http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you must use the [$_FILE](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) super global:

```
if($_FILES["game_file"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $game_tmp = $_FILES['game_file']['tmp_name'];
    $game_name = $_FILES['game_file']['name'];
    $game_dest = "/games/" . $game_name;

    if (move_uploaded_file($game_tmp, $game_dest)) {
        echo "<b>SUCCESS:</b><br />";
    }
    else {
        echo "Error.";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if upload_tmp_dir is not specified, php will use system's default tmp directory. You can use sys_get_temp_dir() function to identify temporary directory being used by PHP.
Have you tried printing $game_file var?
If not, try print_r($game_file) or var_dump($game_file) to view if its actually being set. You can also print $_FILE to see error message (http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

move_uploaded_file could fail for many reason. Also, confirm if the destination directory exists and is writable.

Answer (score 0):

Typos:

```
$game_dest = "/games/" . game_name;
                         ^---you forgot a $ here
```

That's an undefined constant, so PHP will "politely" treat it as an unquoted string, and you're generating `"/games/game_name"` instead.

never **EVER** do devel/debug work in PHP with display_errors and error_reporting turned off. It's the equivalent of going "lalalalala can't hear you" with your fingers stuffed in your ears.

And you're also simply assuming your upload succeeded. There's a `['error']` parameter in $_FILES for a reason. Check it **FIRST**, before you start fiddling with a file that may not even be there.

Comment: I checked the ['error'] for the file and its output was 0. And I just mistyped. I have the $ in my variable file. So that's not the problem but thanks for the response.